# How does `parent` field in this model change when we comment and reply, please explain it?

Tags: python, django

I am reading some codes and I have difficult time understanding `Comment.objects.filter(parent=self)`, codes below:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'[{self.user}] commented on [{self.object_id}]'

    @property
    def children(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(parent=self)
```

This is a comment, reply app. This is my understanding about this, please correct me if I am wrong.
`children` property are replies of comments in Django app.

Practically, if I actually comment on a post like `this is a nice post`, the `parent` field in this model will be equal to this instance of comment, namely `this is a nice post`, and if someone reply to this comment as `thank you for comment`, then again that `parent` would be changed with this instance of comment.

I am pretty confused. Can you elaborate it further please thank you ?

Comment: No, that's not what it means at all. It means that the parent is *another instance of Comment*.

Comment: Extremely sorry, but I couldn't understand it. Can you please explain it with the example. Thank you

Comment: Not sure what's unclear. The parent of "thank you for comment" will be "this is a nice post".

Comment: `self` here is the same _model_, not instance.